# How to directly test a Solidity Library with Hardhat/Chai

Tags: solidity, chai, hardhat

I'm trying to test a Solidity Library directly using hardhat and chaï.
This is a Library example I would like to test:

```
library LibTest {
    function testFunc() public view returns(bool) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and this is how I'm trying to test it.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const LibTest = await ethers.getContractFactory("LibTest");
    const libTest = await LibTest.deploy();
    await libTest.deployed();
})

describe('Testing test()', function () {
    it("is working testFunc ?", async function () {
      console.log(await libTest.testFunc());
    })
})
```

But I have the error message:

> ReferenceError: libTest is not defined

I read everything I can on [Chai doc](https://www.chaijs.com/) and [Hardhat doc](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts) but can't found any solution

Answer (score 3):

I would say to use `fixture` and also utilize `waffle` and to deploy the library contract once and save the `snapshot` of the contract:

```
const {loadFixture } = require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers');
const {expect} = require('chai');

const {ethers, waffle} = require('hardhat');

const {deployContract} = waffle;
const LibArtifact = require('../artifacts/contracts/lib.sol/LibTest.json');

describe("Lib tests", function () {
  // We define a fixture to reuse the same setup in every test.
  // We use loadFixture to run this setup once, snapshot that state,
  // and reset Hardhat Network to that snapshopt in every test.
  async function deployOnceFixture() {

    const [owner, ...otherAccounts] = await ethers.getSigners();
    lib = (await deployContract(owner, LibArtifact));

    return { lib, owner, otherAccounts };
  }

  describe("Testing test()", function () {
    it("s working testFunc ?", async function () {
      const { lib } = await loadFixture(deployOnceFixture); 
      expect(await lib.testFunc()).to.be.true;
    });
  });
});
```

Instructions to add the `waffle` plugin:
[Hardhat-waffle](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-waffle)
Basically, you need to install the libraries:

`npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle 'ethereum-waffle@^3.0.0' @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers 'ethers@^5.0.0'`

And then import `hardhat-waffle` in the `hardhat-config.js` file:

`require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");`

Also, notice I put the `test` file in a `test` directory so I needed to go back one folder to find `artifacts` generated by running `npx hardhat compile`.
For convenience I pushed the solution in a Github repo: https://github.com/Tahlil/run-solidity-lib

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to go about this is to create a LibTest.sol contract that invokes and tests the Lib itself. And just running abstracted tests in JS/TS to invoke the LibTest contract, connecting the Lib.sol contract to it during deployment in Hardhat.

```
const Lib = await ethers.getContractFactory("Lib");
const lib = await Lib.deploy();
const LibTest = await ethers.getContractFactory("LibTest", {
    libraries: {
      Lib: lib.address,
    },
  });
const libTest = await LibTest.deploy();
/// later: console.log(await libTest.testLibFunc());
```

LibTest.sol:

```
import "./Lib.sol";
library LibTest {
    function testLibFunc() public view returns(bool) {
        bool response = Lib.testFunc();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Were you able to find a better method?

Comment: This is the way  explained in the official docs: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers#library-linking

Comment: This is essentially what I've implemented here ^ - a LibTest contract that invokes the Lib library. But still that shows you can't exactly test the lib directly by calling functions via JS, you need a separate solidity contract to invoke the lib.